# If a professor analyzed my work, does the university own my idea?

Tags: publications, peer-review, united-states, intellectual-property, patents

If I had completed work on a certain idea, and would like to have it analyzed from an expert in the field. And shared it with a few professors, to get their opinions on my work... would that mean the university has contributed to my work? And somewhat has rights to the idea? Knowing that I never used the university's resources or facilities during the development of this concept.

I wont publish anything, just need an opinion on my work, if it has errors and overall worth pursuing.

Comment: If you want an opinion from someone who is an academic, not an attorney: if we are talking about, say, a paper that you circulate to faculty members for comments, then it seems extremely unlikely that the university would have any legal claim to your ideas.  (I have worked as a professor at my university for years, and I am not aware of any meaningful sense in which my university owns any of my ideas.)  If you want an opinion from an attorney: ask an attorney!

Comment: Nobody "owns" ideas.

Comment: Do you intend to capitalize on your work in any way? How you share your work may affect the process to obtain to patents or inventions. Who actually has a stake in your work would matter as well (e.g. you used an ATCC cell line under a material transfer agreement to do your work, they still own the cell line and you would need to license their cell line to commercialize your work, for example.). You institution should have an intellectual property lawyer for these matters. Things to consider are non-disclosure agreements and MTA's of your own. IANAL.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question for the legal department at your university. At the university where I teach, there is a standard software license agreement form that I sign with students to basically ensure that software is owned by everyone at the end of the class. But your university will likely have its own rules and policies. If you have your own attorney, you can work with the university to modify such agreements.

Comment: I don't want to downvote your answer, but if you're really concerned about your intellectual property then you MUST retain your own lawyer. Your university's lawyers are paid to argue that they own anything and everything they can lay claim to. Your lawyer is paid to defend you. Simply asking your university's legal department is a bad course of action.

Comment: I agree. Retaining your own lawyer is the best course of action. But some schools do offer legal services to students. I meant to suggest that as a starting point, especially since most students can't afford lawyer fees. No doubt hiring your own layer is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, ask a lawyer.

One general point worth making- undergraduate students and graduate students are very different in this regard. My university explicitly disclaims any interest in work stemming from undergraduate coursework. Graduate students are the exact opposite- work conducted at the university in the course of graduate studies is explicitly owned by the university. My understanding is that this is a fairly common situation, [but not always](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/01/04/education/edlife/whoseidea-t.html).

With respect to your specific question, it sounds like you want to know how little has to happen before the university has a claim over your work. A university *probably* has a claim to any work that is related to your university work, or any work that was accomplished with university resources or any of the university's proprietary information. You're potentially putting yourself in legal jeopardy if you're using *any university resources*, even something as ubiquitous as a university-owned computer, a university-provided internet connection, or the the office you sit in.

One really good reason to consult a lawyer is because state laws vary on this issue. For example, California has [relatively strong protections](http://law.justia.com/codes/california/2011/lab/division-3/2870-2872/2870) for employee-generated intellectual property. Other states do not.

A good rule of thumb, especially in your position, is to document the current state of your work before you bring it into the university context so there is no question as to what you exclusively own. Then, as you work on your side-projects while at the university it is also important to document how your work was not performed on university time or with university resources. Note that if your side-project is related to the scope or content of your employment with the university then it will be extremely hard to argue that the university has no interest there.

If you are a graduate student or employee of the university then there is certainly a contract somewhere that spells out the university's rights and your obligations. If you are an undergraduate student then there is probably a policy that covers the same.

But again, ask a lawyer.